# Given an RE, derive the largest substring match

Tags: regex, string, theory

I'm looking for a bit of code that will:

```
Given regular expression E, derive the longest string X
such that for every S, X is a substring of S iff S will match E
```

examples:

```
E = "a", X = "a"
E = "^a$", X = "a"
E = "a(b|c)", X = "a"
E = "[ab]", X = ""
```

context:  I want to match some regular expressions against a data
store that only supports substring searching.  It would be nice
to optimize the regular expression searching by applying a substring
search to the data store to reduce the amount of data transferred
as much as possible.

example 2:

If I want to catch "error foo", "error bar", "error baz", I might specify

```
error: (foo|bar|baz)
```

and send

```
search "error: "
```

to the data store, and then regexping the returned items.

Thanks!

Comment: If E = "a(b|c)def" then is X = "def"?  Searching for "def" isn't immediately helpful without extra information.
Oh, and should all those "S =" be "X ="?

Comment: (1) Yes, if I can tell the datastore to search for "def" then I can apply the regular expression to a hopefully smaller set of data.  Testing on some hand-generated examples show a good speedup.  (2), yep, S should be X, fixed, thanks!

Comment: So, what should be returned for "^[^a]{1,10}a$"?

Comment: I think "^[^a]{1,10}a$" should return "a", since all matches will have at least substring "a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, you could try to split the regex at all non-unique ((a|b), [ab]) matches, and then look for the longest string in the resulting array. Something like

```
$foo = longest(regex_split($regex, '(\(.*?\|.*?\))|(\[.*?\])'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe convert RE to a finite state automata and look for the longest part that needs to be present in a path between start and finish states... Geometric thinking with a graph can be easier to you, at least it is in my case.